# Mожно ли узнать количество строк в JTextArea сформированых автопереносом?

Tags: java, swing

Здравствуйте!

Есть поле `JTextArea` c включёнными настройками автопереноса:

```
setLineWrap(true);
setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

Текст в поле добавляется сплошной строкой, в зависимости от размера окна, поле `JTextArea` формирует n-е количество строк, могу ли я считывать данный параметр?

Answer (score 0):

`getLineCount()` вернет вам количество строк.

Comment: К сожалению getLineCount() возвращает мне всегда 1. Потому, что исходный текст помещается в JTextArea одной строкой. Но если окно уменьшить строк в поле становиться больше одной, а их количество не меняется. getLineCount() по прежнему будет возвращать 1.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел на просторах [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627776/how-to-count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-jtextarea-include-wrap), уже реализованный метод `getWrappedLines`
класса `RXTextUtilities.java` стороннего разработчика. Исходный [файл](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/26/text-utilities/).